# Is $f(N)= \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} {n\choose N}$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Fix $N \in \mathbb N$ and define $$ f(N)= \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} {n\choose N}$$ Clearly this series is convergent since the binomial coefficient grows at most polynomial in $n$. Can we say anything about the function $f(N)$? Namely, is it bounded or does it go to infinity?

Comment: Perhaps making use od $N$-th derivative of the function $(1-x)^{-1}$ at the point $x=1/2$ may help.

Comment: Many thanks-indeed, sorry I missed that! The value appears to be 2 following your suggestion. Indeed, the power series for $x^N(1-x)^{-N-1}$ is $\sum_{n=N}^\infty x^n {n\choose N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ Thus
$$N!\,(1-x)^{-1-N}={d^N\over dx^N}(1-x)^{-1} ={N!\over x^N}\sum_{n=N}^\infty {n\choose N}x^n$$
Therefore
$$x^N(1-x)^{-1-N}=\sum_{n=N}^\infty {n\choose N}x^n$$
Plugging in $x={1\over 2}$ gives
$$2=\sum_{n=N}^\infty {n\choose N}{1\over 2^n}$$

Answer (score -1):

You have
$$
S=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\binom {n}{N}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2^N}\frac{N!}{N!(N-N)!} + \frac{1}{2^{N+1}}\frac{(N+1)!}{N!(N + 1-N)!}+\frac{1}{2^{N+2}}\frac{(N+2)!}{N!(N + 2-N)!}+...
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{n!}{n!}-\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
which is a geometric series
$$
S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^N} \frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}
$$

Comment: As is you appear to have $S=0$, so there must be some typo or algebra error.

Comment: I do not understand what is happening: you are writing the sum as a difference of two sums, but these two sums appear to be the same? So S=0? but then you use this to prove that S is positive. I am confused.